# Wordpress:How position:sticky an element in the sidebar

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to make one element in the sidebar **css position:sticky**.
I've added the image to the Sidebar - using the Customisation feature.
And added the css - using Customisation/Additional CSS.
But the element scrolls normally with the other elements in the sidebar.

The html looks like this (just an extracted bit):

```
...
        <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sidebar-core">

                        
        <aside class="widget widget_recent_entries">
        <h3 class="widget-title">Recent Posts</h3>
        <ul>
                                            <li>
                    <a href="http://astondb7.com/aston-martin-db7-volante-for-sale/">Aston Martin DB7 Volante &#8211; For Sale</a>
                                    </li>
                                            <li>
                    <a href="http://astondb7.com/v12vanquish-link/">How a DB7 and a Vanquish specialist met</a>
                                    </li>
                                            <li>
                    <a href="http://astondb7.com/6-cylinder-cam-cover/">6 cylinder Cam Cover</a>
                                    </li>
                                            <li>
                    <a href="http://astondb7.com/aston-martin-db7-dashboard-repair/">Aston Martin DB7 Dashboard Repair</a>
                                    </li>
                    </ul>

        </aside><aside class="widget rl-image-widget"><h3 class="widget-title"></h3><img class="rl-image-widget-image" src="http://astondb7.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/AstonMartinBadgeA.png" width="800" height="240" title="Aston Martin Badge" alt="Aston Martin Badge" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;" /><div class="rl-image-widget-text"></div></aside>
        </div>
        </div><!-- #sidebar -->
...
```

And the css is:

```
.rl-image-widget-image  { 
position: sticky;  
position: -webkit-sticky;  
width: 300px;   
height: 80px;  
top: 60px;   
justify-content: center;  
align-items: center;    
    }
#sidebar-core  { height: 800px; }
```

I've tried adding 'overflow:visible' to the parent elements, but didn't solve it.

Site is runnning WP5.6.2  and the the Shuttle theme.

It reacts to position:fixed, and position:absolute, but not 'sticky' ;(

Answer (score 0):

Add a sticky class to parent div i.e.:

```
aside.widget.rl-image-widget {
    position: sticky;
    top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried your suggestion, using Chrome-Developers-Tools, but still it isn't sticky

Comment: To clarify my comment above, it took me some time to realise I was giving Height to the grand-parent, not parent - it was the formatting of the html that threw me.  I've now understood & followed your answer and made the 'aside.widget.rl-image-widget'   sticky, and its parent 'sidebar-core' height:999px.  But doesn't seem to work.  Currently, when the page is scrolled up, the sidebar moves with it, and may go out of screen if the blog is long.   I'm trying to make the image (on the sidebar) stick at the top of the page.

Comment: I found this: https://codepen.io/clairecodes/pen/bvWKdr which shows how simple sticky is to apply, but I can't make it work in my Wordpress sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was the '**parent**' that must not have 'overflow: hidden' but then I read that it's **ANY ancestor**.  So tracking back, I found that the theme's 'Content' is/was 'overflow: hidden' - I changed it to 'visible' - and now my element is 'sticky'.  Now I have to find any ramifications of so doing.